# Instalation of snap okular(pdf viewer KDE) on Xubuntu 16.04.5 issues

Tags: installation, kde, xubuntu, okular

I decided to install okular (PDF Viewer KDE) on my system Xubuntu 16.04.5 (I installed via snap store) , I can open okular but the window has no icons only text, it works: open pdf files, copy images from pdf files and so on. How can I configure okular to run smoothly with Xubuntu ? I read some tutorials but I couldn't fix it. I attached a screenshot of my last attempt to fix but no avail.[image: snap connect]
[image: run okular from terminal]

Comment: I haven't done anything with snap, so this is just a wild guess.  Two thoughts.  1. Most of the KDE utilities require a large collection of KDE components.  You can install what seems like a simple utility, and the installation will include a long list of other KDE stuff.  You might have different luck if you install the normal package from the Ubuntu repository.  2. It sounds like you're only missing icons, and you have an error message that the icon theme is missing.   Try changing the icon theme in system settings.  (cont'd)

Comment: If the package is looking for that theme and it isn't installed, add the theme.  Otherwise try a different icon theme.  There are sometimes weird incompatibilities between certain icon themes and certain applications.

Comment: @fixer1234 Ok, I have Adwaita theme and Adwaita icons installed in /usr/share/themes , /usr/shere/icons . Where snap okular looks for theme and icons ?? Another location ? thks.

Comment: @fixer1234 Why is okular looking for Adwaita theme and icons ? I have another theme installed on Xubuntu.

Comment: As a first step, I would rule out a snap issue by uninstalling Okular, and reinstalling it as a regular package from the Ubuntu repository.

Comment: @fixer1234 yes, this is a solution (I think so), I have Amarok (KDE player) installed (long time ago) via apt install and runs normally with the theme I had set in my system.thks.